# How to run scheduled python script in cpanel

Tags: python-3.x, cron, scheduled-tasks, cpanel, web-hosting

I just bought new webhosting for running python script 24/7 without stopping. Webhosting service provider given a cpanel. I'm having terminal, ssh and python app for web apps.

My python script scrapes data from the web and send the report to the email. I have created a Cron Job command

```
python /home/sdfedse/public_html/main.py    

both I have tried

/usr/local/bin/python -q /home/sdfedse/public_html/newsmp/main.py
```

Nothing is working. Any suggestions how to run python script 24/7 without stopping.

Comment: what does like script itself look like? Does it keep running once its executed?

Comment: Hi @BijayRegmi , I used schedule library and it will run as per schedule once the script file main.py start running.